# php upload image, what if uploaded file contains virus

Tags: file-upload

I'm asking what if the uploaded file form an html form contains a virus...

If the server has a good antivirus, what would it do ? would it automatically prevent the file from being uploaded? or I should do some coding to be sure it's a healthy file?

Answer (score 1):

If it's being uploaded onto the database.. not 100% sure. I don't think it would be detected. The database have to be scanned by the AV. Most AV exclude DB for performance. If it's stored on the filesystem directly, it may quarantine

So take the file, create a php function to generate a Sha256 Hash of the file itself and have the file scanned using the VirusTotal API. If it is/has a virus from any vendor, you can purge the file. If you need a special whitelist, then create a whitelist and create your own custom table for whitelisting files with a SHA256 hash.

So once a user's file is uploaded, just leave a notice that it's being checked by moderators. Then have a cron job/sch task that checks on hash results every 30 minutes. Have a few extra fields in your UserUploads table for the FileHash, and a Safe/Virus Field. You want to have those 2 fields separate or simply use 0, 1, 2 in the Safe field to consolidate the Virus/Safe field. So the user's file starts at 0... If its scanned and safe, it gets a 1, if its confirmed for a virus it gets a 2. You can send off an email to the user saying, This file is infected and allow them to send a reply for 72+ hours or so. If it's just a false positive, you can whitelist the hash yourself by updating the field to 1. You can reduce your efforts by scanning your own database first to see if other users are uploading the same files, automatically whitelist them if they exist in your DB & their Safe field is set to 1.

Suggestive table:

```
FileUploadHash  UserID   Safe  Virus  FileName    Blobdata
--------------  -------  ----  -----  ----------  ---------
SHA256 Hash     ######     0     1    xyajss.pdf  {bin vomit}
SHA256 Hash     ######     1     0    2021jf.png  {bin vomit}
```

So do your loop thru these results and purge where virus = 1. Purge the file and send an email to the user that their file was deemed unsafe and was administratively removed.... Apologies...inconvenience.. blah blah. Then you can allow the users to access based on the "Safe" field. So if the file is safe... do xyz load to make the file content available on your site.

Here's the reference for the VirusTotal Api. They literally have code for dozens of coding languages and implementations.

https://www.virustotal.com/en/documentation/public-api/